# Which structural directive is better to show only one element if multiple conditions are true?

Tags: angular

Let's say I have an input field which has following validation:

- value should not be empty
- value must be at least 5 characters long,
- value should end with @gmail.com

Now I want to show only one of these errors, but it is possible that multiple errors matches the condition for example if I say input should be at least 5 characters long, then first error which say value is required matches the condition and this will cause both errors to show.. This is just example..

I want some flow like this:

- Input.errors.required ? if (true) then error msg should be "input is required" and flow should BREAK,,, else
- Input.errors.length < 5 ? if (true) then error msg should be "input should be 5 characters long" BREAK FLOW else continue and so on

Comment: Why not just do your validation in your controller/code and create an array of error strings, then just `*ngFor` over them? Sounds like you're trying to do too much in your view/HTML.

Comment: Sir sorry it was my mistake, I got the solution, Actually angular (in reactive form approach) gives only one error per input, my problem solved sir, thank you a lot